# How to write an SQL query that displays the top 5 items sold in the same cart with a particular product?

Tags: sql, product, shopping-cart, ranking

I have a table with the columns order_id, customer id, product id

I want to rank the top 5 product_id sold WITH product_id 257.

Do I have to make a new column for all products sold with product_id 257? and then rank them?

Or is there a way to filter the data?

Please help point me in the right direction!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This query is:

- A filter to get the right orders.
- Aggregation.
- Another filter to get the top 5.

In SQL, this looks like:

```
select t.product_id, count(*)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.order_id = t.order_id and t2.product_id = 257
             ) and
      t.product_id = 257
group by t.product_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 5 rows only;
```